# Odd Facebook IDs being returned

Tags: facebook-fql

I've got some code which executes the following FQL:

"SELECT name, page_url, page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid= $uid )";

Where $uid the facebook user ID of a user.

For one user the code returns several rows - all with the same name but DIFFERENT page_ids. If I search for the page name on Facebook I only get one single hit. So anyone got any ideas on how to remove the "rogue" entries?

Answer (score 0):

Some of those pages, could be admin pages created when a user likes an external page that is connected to an app.  To which you probably do not want to delete them.  "Admin pages will not show up in search, but will show with accounts and manage_pages perms.

Comment: As I posted above - they seem to be pages associated with applications which the user did not create but which he is an admin for. I've changed my code so that it indicates to the end user which is which so at least they're picking the rightone

Answer (score 0):

THey could be unpublished pages or open graph pages; just because you can't find it in public search doesn't mean it doesn't exist - it should be possible by searching the page's info to determine which is likely to be the one you're really looking for (i.e the one with fans and tabs and wall posts )

Comment: I found out what they are - they are applications, which the user never actually created - he doesn't even have a developer account!. The url for the page gives it away as it is set to 

https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=